Angular 17 shows time behind by several hours when using datetime-local
The date-time field is shown using this code below. I chose the correct date and time which is 07/06/2024 11:43 AM when submitting the form:
<input type="datetime-local" [(ngModel)]="item.date">

The API call shows the data below in this format:
createdAt: "2024-06-07T06:13:51.050Z"
date: "2024-06-07T11:43:00.000Z"
updatedAt: "2024-06-07T06:13:51.050Z"

Using {{item.createdAt | date: 'dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm a'}} shows the
createdAt as 07/06/2024 11:43 AM which is the correct time. Same correct time for updatedAt too.
However, using {{item.date | date: 'dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm a'}} shows the
date as 07/06/2024 05:13 PM incorrectly and is ahead by 6.5 hours.
I'm based in India with timezone +5:30pm. What could be wrong here?
It's like createdAt and updatedAt is on a different timezone while date is a different timezone.

For me, the given date strings give consistent results, and the date string is not off. Also the strings are in the exact same format, so it would be very strange if one of them would behave differently. It would be helpful to have a minimal reproduction.

@JSONDerulo Great username :) and thank you for the comment. However, it would be impossible to reproduce the scenario with the backend.

@JSONDerulo: I tried something like this in the .TS file but I got an error this.date = new Date().toLocaleString("en-US", {timeZone: "Asia/Kolkata"});

Why do you think 05:13 PM is wrong? For the createdAt case, if you add 6.5 hours to the UTC date, you get 11:43. For the date case, if you add 6.5 hours to the UTC date, you get 17:13, which is equivalent to 05:13 PM. So I wonder why you think that the date is off.

*5.5 hours of course... But still the expectation seems to be wrong.

@JSONDerulo Yes, there's a difference of 5.5 hours. I'm trying to find a solution to the difference in time. I added the date-time as 11:43 AM in the form when submitting but it shows as 05:13 PM.

Then probably the time zone is not considered when sending the date to the backend. Maybe you can transform the date to an ISO string for the backend request with .toISOString()?

You are using hh 12 hour format. After midday, it will start at 01 again. Also you are not using an AM/PM prefix, which makes the time look off. But the date itself is perfectly fine, it's just formatted unexpectedly.
If you want to add AM/PM prefix, add a at the end:
{{item.date | date: 'dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm a'}} -> '07/06/2024 05:13 PM'

Or if you want to use the 24 hour format, replace hh with HH:
{{item.date | date: 'dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm'}} -> '07/06/2024 17:13'

For more info, see the docs

I added the AM/PM and found out my date is ahead by 6.5 hours. See my updated question please. How can fix this?

@ElaineByene Your calculation is incorrect time difference calculator

ah yes.. ahead by 5.5 hours. How can i fix this difference? createdAt and updateAt date and time is correct while the date field is ahead by 5.5 hours. i correctly added the date and time in the datetime-local field.

@ElaineByene "2024-06-07T11:43:00.000Z" UTC + 5:30 hours (India Timezone) => 07/06/2024 05:13 PM Javascirpt is showing the correct date, just continue development, there is no issue to fix :) if you want to show the UTC date, check the below deleted answer!

@NarenMurali But I submitted the time as 11:43AM which got converted to 5:13PM, and so the date should be "2024-06-07T06:13:51.050Z", same as createdAt and updatedAt. Also, I cannot see the deleted answer!
